# How to find document from collection based on nested values

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

How to get document by nested value such as "brand" or "storageId" from "trigger.value".

```
{
    "_id":  "60aee243fff5082ca6fba951",
    "status": "Good",
    "trigger": {
        "value": "{"brand":"A","storageId":"2","emplId":"3"}"
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking to get only selective values returned from the DB?

Comment: I would like to get elements which have values  "brand" = A and "storageId"  = 2

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick

```
db.collection.find({"trigger.value.brand":"A"})
```

You could add more columns by CSV. This practice is known as dot notations. More on this [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation)